# подскажите с nvidia-smi, видеокарта криво отвечает

Tags: c++, cmd, драйвер, nvidia, gpu

Видеокарта GeForce GTX 1060 3GB.
Пытаюсь ускорить работу видеокарты драйверной утилитой "nvidia-smi" по инструкции https://1ethereum.ru/razgon-videokart-nvidia-i-amd-radeon-dlya-majninga/#___Nvidia через cmd ввожу команды, но результат явно не по образцу[image: попытки определить параметры] драйвера стоят самые свежие. cmd запускаю от администратора. MSI burner и GPU-Z все видят и все меняется. Мне необходимо выполнять эти команды как минимум через nvidia-smi для автоматизации или подскажите программную реализацию на c++ пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено, на видеокартах 10ХХ nvidia-smi не работает.